# using a boost::flyweight type with std::unique_ptr transparently

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to write some code to manage large numbers of sprites on the screen using Allegro 5 as the graphics engine.

As many of the sprites will be using the same underlying bitmap, I'd like to use the boost::flyweight library to template the bitmap type, so bitmaps which are associated with similar object types will not be repeatedly loaded into memory.

The ALLEGRO_BITMAP straight-C type is wrapped up in a structure allegro_bitmap_t with appropriate user-defined conversions so it can be used directly as the underlying C type when necessary. I'm trying to set up the flyweight type so that it can be dereferenced from the unique_ptr the same as the "regular" type transparently, without calling the "get" method of the unique_ptr, dereferencing, and then the "get" method for the boost::flyweight type repeatedly.

```
namespace GraphicsTypes {

using allegro_bitmap_t = struct B
{
public:
    B(int bitmap_w, int bitmap_h) : current_id(id())
    {
        _bitmap_ptr = al_create_bitmap(bitmap_w, bitmap_h);
        if (_bitmap_ptr == nullptr) throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    B(const char* filename) : current_id(id())
    {
        _bitmap_ptr = al_load_bitmap(filename);
        if (_bitmap_ptr == nullptr) throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    ~B() = default;

    operator ALLEGRO_BITMAP*() const
    {
        return _bitmap_ptr;
    }

    const ALLEGRO_BITMAP& operator* () const
    {
        return *_bitmap_ptr;
    }

    const int current_id;

private:
    static int id()
    {
       static int _id = 0;
       return _id++;
    }

    ALLEGRO_BITMAP* _bitmap_ptr;
}; 

inline std::size_t hash_value(const B& b)
{
    return boost::hash<int>()(b.current_id);
}

inline bool operator==(const B& l,const B& r)
{
    return l.current_id == r.current_id;
}

inline bool operator!=(const B& l,const B& r)
{
    return !(l.current_id == r.current_id);
}

}
```

Is there a way to construct a "wrapper" type, something like allegro_flyweight_bitmap_t so dereferencing to the underlying bitmap works automagically?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you have something like `std::unique_ptr<boost::flyweight<ALLEGRO_BITMAP>> _bitmap_ptr;` and you want to avoid doing `ALLEGRO_BITMAP * get() { return _bitmap_ptr.get().get(); }` ?

Comment: @Recker I'm actually using the "allegro_bitmap_t" wrapper type there instead of "ALLEGRO_BITMAP" but yes that looks essentially correct.

This thread archived by Google Groups had some Boost users on Usenet discussing a situation that seemed related, but unfortunately I couldn't get the code they had  listed to work in my situation.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/Ig3i_VMWOy4

Comment: @Recker As it stands now, I'm able to use an allegro_bitmap_t pointer/reference in various ways and have it behave as an ALLEGRO_BITMAP reference. I'd like to be able to do something like call .get() the unique_ptr to the flyweight variant and have that reference behave identically, if that's possible, and using the -> operator on the unique_ptr works "correctly" without intermediate calls

Comment: Arent there any observers or getters for `allegro_bitmap_t` type that would return the pointer to the type?